# I can't focus on so many unnecessary subjects at my university, do i really need a graduate diploma to get a job eventually?

Tags: university

I am currently finishing my first year at university of Computer Science and IT, it has been a good journey so far and I have passed nine out of eleven subjects, two are left to be finished in August.

I do not feel like I have learned anything except mathematical problems in programming that do not interest me because i would like to do app developing and website backend and frontend. Most of the time I spent studying from youtube or community on google more than actual professors at university.

I feel empty and obligated to do my chores, both subjects I have left for August are mathematics and it stresses me so much. I don't feel like I will ever finish this university and get a job, my parents force me to get that graduate diploma which doesn't mean much as most programmers say but I never wondered if it mattered that much until now?

I hope some of you could answer my question, sorry for my grammar mistakes I am just too tired from all the studying to focus on English.

Comment: If you have no interest in computer science, you probably shouldnt be studying it. But I don't see a question here.

Comment: do i really need a graduate diploma to get a job eventually? - of course not.

Comment: @Arno, the question is in the title.

Comment: Sounds like university coursework is not the right path for you. Explore community colleges or vocational schools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some jobs, yes you do. For others, not at all. It depends on the job and on what opportunities it provides. Jobs that require university education often have more opportunities in the future.

But, I know that in some places, family pressures can be intense. Especially if one or both parents has misconceptions and prejudices. It is hard to resist, but it won't go on forever (in most families). This is especially the case if the family's financial support is required or if the culture simply requires it.

But, I think that the family issue is more critical to you at this moment than the others. Perhaps you can change majors to something that suits you better.

And, there is a lot to learn beyond programming, though programming ability is needed for web development. Math also.

Comment: Hahaha. The last line is great!

Answer (score 17):

Have you ever watched the movie [The Karate Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid)? In this classic American movie, Daniel, a 17 year old high school student in Los Angeles, is being trained in the art of karate by Mr. Miyagi, a wise older man who wants to help Daniel combat a gang of bullies. But Daniel is baffled and frustrated when, instead of teaching him exciting karate techniques, Mr. Miyagi asks him to paint a fence and do other menial chores that don’t seem to have anything to do with karate.

Later in the movie, it is shown how the fence painting and other chores actually helped Daniel learn movements that are crucial to being good at karate and defeating the bullies.

The movie is fiction, but contains a larger truth. The mathematics and other subjects you are learning at university that don’t seem to have anything to do with computer programming or working in IT are teaching you to think better. This will improve your ability to be a good programmer in ways that you can’t even begin to imagine, far beyond what you’ll learn from a course on Java or app development — just like Daniel did not appreciate at first why painting a fence will make him good at karate. On the other hand, savvy employers are well aware of the value of a rigorous education, and having such an education will open all kinds of career opportunities to you that would be very hard to make yourself competitive for otherwise.

Do you need a degree to get a job? Of course not. But getting “a job” is hardly an ambitious goal to have in life. A degree will vastly improve your future ability to have a rewarding career doing things that you enjoy and fulfill your potential, either as a programmer or doing anything else.

Comment: The Karate Kid analogy also works great for PhD studies in the sciences - Daniel is made to do annoying chores for his teacher all day long, which are only occasionally interrupted with actual subject teaching (typically whenever Daniel is on the brink of quitting). Yet somehow, with the mysterious speed of plot, Daniel ends up a subject expert anyway, and at the end all involved people agree that it was a great experience.

Comment: @xLeitix absolutely. It’s an amazing metaphor, one of the best I know about, for learning of all kinds. I realized that myself some years ago and then discovered I wasn’t the only one - the Karate Kid is mentioned in countless blogs and articles on education, see [here](https://edcrocks.com/2021/02/07/wax-on-wax-off-karate-kids-lesson-about-drilling/) for one example (or Google “karate kid education”).